# Error 438: object doesn't support pr

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a code to move up the value in column B to be in the same row of the column A value. When i run the below code, it shows error 438 object does not support this property or method.

```
 Sub dataPreprocessing()

Dim counter As Integer
Dim A As String
Dim i As Long
counter = 0

For i = 1 To 2500
    Sheet1("test1").Range("B" & i).Select
    If IsEmpty((Sheet1("test1").Range("B[i]").Value)) Then
        counter = counter + 1
    Else
       A = Sheet1("test1").Range("B[i]").Value
       Sheet1("test1").Range("B" & i - (counter - 1)).Select
       Set Sheet1("test1").Range("B[i-(counter-1)]").Value = A
       Sheet1("test1").Range("B" & i).Select
       Set Sheet1("test1").Range("B[i]").Value = ""
       counter = 0

    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: `Sheet1("test1").Range("B[i]").Select` should be `Sheet1("test1").Range("B" & i).Select`

Comment: even when replaced with  Sheet1("test1").Range("B" & i).Select   it shows the same error!

Comment: Can you update the question with new code. And mention which line it is you are having problem?

Comment: `Sheet1("test1").Range("B[i]").Select` should be `Sheets("test1").Range("B" & i).Select`

Comment: it doesn't show the line, it only show a message saying that  "run-time error 438  object does not support this property or method"

Comment: See my updated line and update the code with the edits suggested so that it is easier for me to see what is going on...

Comment: why are you doing all those `select` statements .... they serve no function in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what you are trying to do with respect to the logic but the below should work.

Take due note on how I use `Sheets("test1")` Vs `Sheet1` in both the cases.

Also Range is always addressed like "A1"/"B2500" not "A[1]"/"B[2500]".

Those are the two changes I made.

You can work with the below::

```
Sub dataPreprocessing()

    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim A As String
    Dim i As Long
    counter = 0

    For i = 1 To 2500
        Sheets("test1").Range("B" & i).Select
        If IsEmpty((Sheets("test1").Range("B" & i).Value)) Then
            counter = counter + 1
        Else
           A = Sheets("test1").Range("B" & i).Value
           Sheets("test1").Range("B" & i - (counter - 1)).Select
           Sheets("test1").Range("B" & (i - (counter - 1))).Value = A
           Sheets("test1").Range("B" & i).Select
           Sheets("test1").Range("B" & i).Value = ""
           counter = 0

        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

---

**OR**

---

```
Sub dataPreprocessing()

    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim A As String
    Dim i As Long
    counter = 0

    For i = 1 To 2500
        Sheet1.Range("B" & i).Select
        If IsEmpty((Sheet1.Range("B" & i).Value)) Then
            counter = counter + 1
        Else
           A = Sheet1.Range("B" & i).Value
           Sheet1.Range("B" & i - (counter - 1)).Select
           Sheet1.Range("B" & (i - (counter - 1))).Value = A
           Sheet1.Range("B" & i).Select
           Sheet1.Range("B" & i).Value = ""
           counter = 0

        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: downvote ... the `select` statements do not serve any function in the code that you posted .... you are using the `set` statements incorrectly

Comment: @jsotola I was just correcting one component of the users main error. Agree that set is used for objects, but in this case does not throw an error and works appropriately

Comment: Cool, now you can remove all the `. Select` statements and the code would work just fine! And it will run faster.